# Put a background image in footer in Word 2010?

Tags: microsoft-word, images, microsoft-word-2010, footers, background

I want to put a background image in the footer, but can only figure out how to put an actual image in.

I tried putting an actual image in but had some issues with doing so.

I need the background image to be placed at the bottom right corner so there is NO space at all between the image and the side/bottom of the page.

I was able to do this with an image, but because I want to add some text to the left of it I had to add a table in to do so.

To get the image to sit flush on the right side and bottom I had to drag the bars in Word to allow it to expand that far and also make the "Footer from bottom" be `0.0 cm`; however when I added the table I had to expand it to the edge of the page, but then when I added the image into it the image was partly off the right of the page; and another issue was the table wouldn't expand to the bottom of the page completely.

So, my question is, how can I input an image without affecting the other content, or input an image + content together without the aforementioned issues stated above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To add a background picture into the Footer area of a page, you have to put it into the Header. Set the wrap on the picture to Behind Text and then drag it down the page to the Footer area.

Background page pictures are always anchored to the Header paragraph. They are not anchored in the Footer.

If you only want it showing in the Footer, you will also have to size it according to the height of your footer area.

Comment: Actually, there is nothing that prevents a full-page-size image in the footer.

Comment: @CharlesKenyon please read the stem of my last sentence ... “If you only want it showing in the Footer, ..."